# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.Sahil.Main

Tags: java, maven

Am making a Discord bot and I want the bot file in "jar" format so I can run it effectively, but every time I try to build a jar file out of it throws some sort of error, Such as

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.Sahil.Main Caused by:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.Sahil.Main
```

or

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.Sahil.Main
```

First, it used to show the second error but after spending some time on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PRlxPOyjUyk) I made some changes and I think it got worse. I've never tried maven so completely blind.

[my project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lry8g.png)

pom file

```
<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>Bot</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>

</dependencies>
```

I removed my dependencies as I believe they won't be necessary for this, please do let me know if I need to provide them will do so.

Comment: [How can I create an executable JAR with dependencies using Maven?](//stackoverflow.com/q/574594)

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that your jar file does not contain the class file that the JVM tries to invoke `main` in.

If you look inside your jar file (it is just a zip file) you will most likely find that it does not contain a file with the exact name `com/Sahil/Main.class`.

Fix your jar creation so that file is present.   You will *then* find that it cannot find classes from your dependencies.  That is a different problem with several solutions.  As @Tom suggests, look at [How can I create an executable JAR with dependencies using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/574594) to find out which one suits you best.